# Complexity of building a set from list?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the computational complexity of the following operation:

```
list1 = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4]
set1 = set(list)
```

Comment: wouldn't that be implementation dependent? (but probably O(N))

Comment: Appears this has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642155/what-is-time-complexity-of-the-python-list-to-set-conversion

Answer (score 0):

It is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the list. `set()` is essentially iterating over the list and adding each of those elements to a hash table.