# why building a set from vector is O(N)

Tags: c++, vector, set, time-complexity, insertion

As we know that set is implemented using red-black trees so inserting an element will be a task of O(log N) complexity. But if we are given a vector of n distinct integer so making a set out of it should by NlogN task. But in many places, I found it is given as O(N). Can someone please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Link to the place where I read this
[Complexity of building a set from list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393707/complexity-of-building-a-set-from-list)

Comment: Why do you think it's O(n)? Constructing a set from a vector is O(n*log n).

Comment: @fdan that's the question, why does someone claim it's O(n) when it's not obvious why it would be the case?  A link to one of those "many places" would have helped.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about any particular example which you think you are describing. It could be that your case doesn't meet the terms set forth in this question, or it could be a best-case scenario (sorting an array which is already sorted) in which case it's irrelevant.

Comment: A heap(priority queue) takes `O(N)` time to build provided you've all `N` elements readily available. Set takes `O(NlogN)` no matter what.

Comment: `But in many places, I found it is given as O(N)` We can not tell you about situations that we are unaware of. Please name (link) these many places (or at least the top one). Maybe there are more constraints on the input that you are glossing over?

Comment: The claim is incorrect. If we could construct a set from an *unsorted* vector in `O(N)`, we would get `O(N)` sorting algorithm.

Comment: "As we know ..." my understanding is rather the reverse: Inserting an element in to a `set` is specified to be a `O(log N)` operation and a red-black tree can achieve that.

Comment: Inserting elements in a heap is O(logN) too, but creating a heap from an array can be done in O(n), although the mathematical proof is a bit long. The theory behind it is that the total number of operations to be done is `n * sum( i / 2^i ) from i = 1 ... logN`, which is less than `2n`, and hence, bounded in O(n).

Comment: "But in many places" Provide links to one or more such places.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Please find the link after edit.

Comment: That place is talking about hash tables, not trees. One down, how many to go?

Comment: so can set be implemented using hashtable also?

Comment: yes, it can be implemented with a hash table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the vector is already sorted, then constructing the `set` is indeed `O(N)` (but in general not!).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set):

```
template< class InputIt >    
set( InputIt first, InputIt last,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

> Range constructor. Constructs the container with the contents of the range [first, last). If multiple elements in the range have keys that compare equivalent, it is unspecified which element is inserted

> Complexity
>
> N log(N) where N = std::distance(first, last) in general, linear in N if the range is already sorted by value_comp().

The relevant quote from the standard is:

> [22.4.6.2#4](http://eel.is/c++draft/set#cons-4) Complexity: Linear in N if the range [first, last) is already sorted using comp and otherwise NlogN, where N is last - first.

The standard only specifies what containers do, not how they accomplish that. Using a red-black tree is typical but not necessary to implement a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: How is it linear? Can someone link me an explanation I didn't find anything related to this.

Comment: @srt1104 I couldn't justify it with mathematics but essentially the operation is linear with a sorted vector because you can use the position that the previous element was inserted at as a hint to insert the next element more quickly.

Comment: Still the tree will have to reorder itself sometime and that's a logN operation.

Comment: @srt1104 Cleverer people than me have said it is O(N) including any rebalancing, in fact the C++ standard guarantees it.

Comment: Note it is only O(N) for constructing a new set, inserting into an existing set is still O(N log(N))

Comment: @srt1104 no, you put the values directly where they should end up. Only if you find the input is unordered do you have to reorder what you've already added

Comment: @john appending a sorted sequence to an existing set is also O(N) in existing implementations, because they just reuse the same algorithm as for constructing from a sorted sequence (repeatedly calling hinted set::insert with end() as the hint)

Comment: @Cubbi I know that, but I recall reading that isn't O(N). The point of what I read was that it was originally assumed that it was O(N) but then someone with a better grasp of the memthemtics pointed out it wasn't and the standard had to be revised. But my recollection might be faulty, this was a long time ago. If anyone has access to the standard now I'd be interested to know.

Comment: @Cubbi So [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) says this `Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just before the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.` I think the point is that if the map already contains elements then you can't guarantee that insertion happens in the position just before the hint. So a single insertion is O(logN) and presumably N insertions are O(NlogN).