# How expensive for container conversion functions in Python?

Tags: python

For example:

```
my_list = list(my_set)

my_set = set(my_list)
```

I often needs to convert them for some index based iteration or efficient loop up. Are they linear for those two operations?

If it is linear, this conversion below is unnecessary?

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]

for n in my_list:
   if n == '2':
      print(yes)

my_set = set(my_list)
if '2' in my_set:
   print(yes)
```

NO need to change the list to set. Right?

Comment: Conversion from set to list and vice versa is linear, yes.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642155/what-is-time-complexity-of-a-list-to-set-conversion) is also useful to refer to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is time complexity of a list to set conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642155/what-is-time-complexity-of-a-list-to-set-conversion)

Comment: How could it not be linear?  Genuinely asking.

Comment: If you are only doing this one containment operation, then yes, the conversion is unnecessary. If you are doing *multiple* containment operations, then a single O(n) operation to support multiple O(1) operations make sense.

Comment: It makes sense. Chepner